# ASP.NET displaying icons different than HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm facing a problem trying to transfer HTML/CSS to ASP.NET. In HTML my icons were displayed in 1 row from 4 icons, and for mobile device in 2x2 rows. Now I actually kind of copy pasted HTML with some small changes like changing /> ending tag. But now it displays 2x2 rows on PC aswell while it should be 1 row with 4 icons. I'm still a student and pretty noob at this so I'd appreciate the help since it's for my thesis. Thanks on advance. (code below)

[image: HTML: How it should be]
[image: ASP.NET: How it shouldn't be]

```css
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  body{
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

  }

  .container{
    margin: auto;
  }


  h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 47px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
  }


  .title{
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }







  form {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .search {
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    border:0px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
  }

  .btnsearch {
    width: 50px;
    height: 31px;
    border-radius: 0px 7px 7px 0px;
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #207cca;
    background-color:#207cca;
    color:#fafafa;
    left: -10px;
  }
  .btnsearch:hover  {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#207cca;
  }





  .icon-div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
  }


  .icon{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 35px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /*background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    td {
        float: left;
        margin-right:10px;
        width: 45%;
    }
    td:nth-child(3) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .icon{
      width:100%!important;
      height:100%!important;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
  }

  
  .icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
    box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }



  .icontext{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;

  }



  .contactbtn{
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 35px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 12px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
    transition-property: box-shadow, transform;

    background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  }

  .contactbtn:hover, .contactbtn:focus, .contactbtn:active {
    box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Schoolreglement_FORM.index1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Knowledge base</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />-->


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!--Title-->
          <section class="container">
          <h1>
            <br />
            <span class="title" >
               <label style="color:#e55643;">Burger</label><label style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</label>
            </span>
            <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
          </h1>
        </section>

        <!--Zoekbalk-->
        <section align="center">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Zoek iets op..." class="search"/>
            <input type="button" value="Zoek" class="btnsearch"/>
        </section>

        <!--Icoontjes-->
        <div style="text-align: center;">

          <div class="icon-div" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a href="afspraken.html">
              <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/reminders_icon@2x.png" class="icon"/>
            </a>
            <span class="icontext">Afspraken</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <img src="https://www.icloud.com/system/cloudos/17BHotfix5/cloudos_foundation/17BHotfix5/en-us/source/resources/images/app_icons/fmf_icon@2x.png" class="icon"/>
            <span class="icontext">Situaties</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <img src="controlcenter.png" class="icon"/>
            <span class="icontext">Grenzen</span>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-div">
            <img src="Multitaks.png" class="icon"/>
            <span class="icontext">Categoriëen</span>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!--Contact-->
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="button" value="contact" class="contactbtn"/>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Compare your original CSS and HTML to the new CSS and HTML and spot the difference?

Comment: Well it's pure copy paste, I didn't change anything, only some ending tags

Comment: Assuming you didn't change anything, they'd be the same. The only other thing to check would be to make sure your browser isn't using an older/cached version of your resources.

Comment: your `form` style has fixed width of 500px ..... then all four can't fit either increase the width of that element or use % size on the buttons

Comment: Thanks for the help @DaniP just saw the answer from someone else it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form {
    /* width: 500px; */ remove the width from form
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px; }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy appreciate it. I was forced to change a form to a section since ASP.NET is between a form. Forgot about it thanks!

Comment: enjoy and keep coding ;)

Comment: Thank, I'll try :)